# i want to delete sqlite row on basis of given id when user select from the list

Tags: android, sqlite

Whenever I run this code, it deletes every item but not '0'index value, and at the same time it replaces '0'index value with anoother value when i reopened a activity , i dont knw on which part am getting problem exactly
here my db class method

```
public boolean deletesinglerow(String rowid) {
    SQLiteDatabase obj = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //return  obj.delete(TABLE_NAME,"ID = ?",new String[]{rowid});
    if (obj.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?", new String[]{rowid}) >0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

it is onitemlongclickmethod

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long iddb) {
        Boolean deletedrows=myDB.deletesinglerow(String.valueOf(iddb));
        if(deletedrows==true){
            Log.d("Clicked item id", " " + iddb);
            Toast.makeText(StarMessages.this,"Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            messageAdapter.remove(arrayList.get(position));
            listView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
            messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(StarMessages.this,"cant delete",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by '0'index value?  Be more specific about the problem.

Comment: for example when i delete the very first value of listview (which have '0'index ) in sqlite it says 'cant del'..

Comment: When you have set id column to Primary key and Autoincrement, it starts with 1 and not 0. There will be no row with Id = 0. So when you say first value  of listview (which have 0 index), for database is index+1 i.e. ID = 0+1 = 1.

Comment: yeah , i set it as a Autoincrement, so can U tell me from where i do change in my code so can i delete the value of seleted index

Comment: continue - i am passing the id of sqlite to db class (i am getting the index of sqlite from the method as 3 argument)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the Listview Long parameter to your database and Applying query on it. That value may not be available in your Database. Pass the Unique that is present in the Database.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the record from ur db u have to specify which record has to be deleted using a unique identifier( like Id: primary Key). Use that key to query delete records

Answer (score 0):

To delete a row from SQLite, the easiest way is to use its unique primary key:

Well, you use the fourth parameter of the OnItemLongClickListeners `onItemLongClick` function. This is the listadapter's item id. 
This item id need to be set to your objects primary key: 
This is done through your ListAdapter's `getItemId` function. So if you want the right ID in `onItemLongClick`, you have to overwrite `getItemId`:

```
public long getItemId (int position) {
    //return whatever ID refers to in your model
}
```

More information:
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId(int)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom adapter, extending from `BaseAdapter`, then what you can do is to pass the id's taken from the your `query` to the adapter. Then you need `override` the `getItemId()` function to return the id of the specified row which is represented in your sqlite database. Then in your `Activity`

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long iddb) {

      Log.d("Clicked item id", " " + iddb); // this will return the actual db id.

            return true; 
        } 
    });
```